# UITextView setup in storyboard not showing at runtime

Tags: swift, xcode10.2

I have a `UITextView` inside a `stackView` laid out in storyboard. But the `textView` doesn't show up when the app is running. There nothing there but empty background. I want the user to be able to tap on the `textView` and enter text just as in a textField. All my other `UITextFields` are working as expected but not the `UITextView`.

I ave tried deleting it and placing a new `UITextView` from the library, I've looked through all the properties that can be set in story board but can't find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Runtime**

[image]

**identityInspector**

[image]

**attributeInspector**

[image]

[size inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggxur.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u66ZA.png)

Comment: what are the constraints of the textview ?

Comment: Please also add a screenshot of the size inspector.

Comment: no constraints added other than those automatically produced by Xcode. I have tried it with and without added constraints and it makes no difference.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the scene structure with the constraints for the views above and below "Notes Text View".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what seemed to solve it was changing the 'Module' setting under the identity inspector to InputBarAccessoryView. Hope that helps!